# titanium: fallback for split window on android

Tags: javascript, mobile, titanium, titanium-mobile

I have developed an iPad application that uses split window. I want this to be run on android devise as well.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: It is not a good thing to go against the device's original design standards. Split window is THE STANDARD in iPad.

Comment: things are running fine on iPad, and I am using split window only. But need the same application to be run on android as well. And as you know android does not support split window so need a fallback in that condition

Comment: As i mentioned, Android will not support Split window functionality. So you have to handle/make slightly different UI.

Answer (score 0):

This can be achieved but you will need to 'fake' the SplitWindow functionality by using two views / windows as a splitWindow isn't supported in the native Android SDK.

You can also use a sliding window there are some open source projects that might help:

[Slider Menu Widget for Andorid](http://www.danielsefton.com/2013/05/slider-menu-widget-v2-for-titanium-alloy/)